# How to make numbering right-to-left in footnotes in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

When using footnotes in Microsoft Word in 2 columns, the numbering will be from left to right.

I'm using Word 2016 (and the problem also appears in other versions)

[image]

like the problem here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/footnote-columns-in-microsoft-word-2016-using/2b7a9fb0-c759-4320-ab4d-b50af715e5ef?auth=1

Note: if i open a new page from MS WORD and make new footnotes, the problem will not appear, but when working in some files the problem occurs (i assured the file is not in compatibility mode).

Comment: Is the section direction right-to-left ? (Layout-Page setup->Layout)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this problem here. I had a look at the XML code of a sample document, and where the section was RTL, the footnotes were laid out RTL. If I tried something more complicated, like having two continuous sections on a page, the layout of the footnotes seems to depend on the section direction of the first section on the page that contains a footnote reference. e.g. if the first is in an LTR section, all the footnotes are laid out LTR, even if everything else is RTL.